# Migrating bioinformatics questions from the Bioinformatics SE chat

Tags: discussion

There's a little bit of frustration in chat with regards to people asking questions that would be better asked in the main site. See [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42086408#42086408), for example. Some people can be encouraged to re-ask the questions themselves, but some prefer leaving the questions along in the chat interface.

How much emphasis should we put into migrating questions?

Answer (score 6):

This is an issue across the SE network. Many people will ask in chat instead of the site. This is annoying for various reasons:

1. When asking in chat, nobody else benefits from the answer. The site doesn't gain any new content and someone with the same question in the future won't find the solution here.
2. Asking a question on the site tends to force people to formulate it clearly and give the necessary background information for it to be answered. Getting this information in chat is often painful, time-consuming and annoying.

So, I tend to ask people to post a question on the site and *then* come to chat to discuss it, if necessary. That seems like the best of both worlds.

Now, there is no way of bringing questions from chat to the site short of someone manually reposting them as questions. Therefore, "migrating" is not an option, sadly. All we can do is ask the user to post a question or, if we find it particularly interesting, to post the question ourselves.

Answer (score 3):

I would find it frustrating to have to link internally to existing questions (and answers) in the chat discussion when questions are duplicated, so would prefer it to be acceptable to migrate well-asked/formulated questions. Perhaps these could be done as community posts to encourage community refinement of both the questions and answers.

Comment: "Migrate" is probably the wrong word, since I don't see a technical way to migrate questions from chat, but the general idea of getting them on the main site I totally back.